# Grep and CMD escaping

Tags: regex, windows, grep, escaping, gnu

I am trying to grep this pattern: `^#include\s+"[^"]+"`

Unfortunately, when I try the following in a Windows batch file, the pipe (`|`) and the `sort` are treated as inputs to `grep`, probably because of the unbalanced quotes.

```
> grep -P '^#include\s+"[^"]+"' --include=*.h --include=*.cpp | sort

grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: sort: No such file or directory
```

I tried different combinations of escaping, both with backslash and with caret, but could not get it to work.

**Edit:**

By trial and error, I got this to work:  `grep -P '^^#include\s+\"[^\"]+\^"' --include=*.h --include=*.cpp | sort`

It is a weird mix of CMD escapes (`^`) and regex escapes (`\`), without an apparent rhyme or reason to which one needs to be used where.

I am leaving the question open in the hope that someone will offer a general explanation.

Comment: Does `grep -P "^#include\s+"^""[^"^""]+"^""" --include=*.h --include=*.cpp | sort` work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not find the pattern

Comment: I suggest to replace each `"` in regular expression search string by `\x22` which is the hexadecimal notation of the straight double quote character and enclose the search string in double quotes to get `^` interpreted as literal character and not as escape character by `cmd.exe`, i.e. use `grep -P "^#include\s+\x22[^\x22\r\n]+\x22" --include=*.h --include=*.cpp | sort`. BTW: Do you know that `\s` matches any whitespace character according to Unicode and not just normal spaces and horizontal tabs? It would be better to use `[\t ]+` instead of `\s+` in the search expression.

Comment: Managed to find a working combination and edited question accordingly, leaving it open because I still don't know **why** it works.  As for the `\s`, I agree but since the question is about escaping I left that part as is.

Answer (score -2):

PowerShell has regex support. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell was installed with it.

=== Do-Grepit.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '*.h','*.cpp' |
    ForEach-Object { Select-String -Pattern '^#include\s+"[^"]+"' -Path $_ }
```

At an interactive console, using aliases could make for less typing, but aliases should not be coded into script files.

```
gci -pa *.h,*.cpp|%{sls '^#include\s+"[^"]+"' $_}
```

If you are desperate to run this from a `cmd` `batch-file`, then you could:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Do-Grepit.ps1"
```

Comment: The question was about CMD, sometimes using a different shell is not possible

Comment: @AlexO, any supported system running `cmd` can use this solution without starting a shell.